# Android repeating alarm not working for next days

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

i am trying to send notification everyday at some periods. its working for the day that i created the alarm. But the next days i am not getting any notification and my ReminderClass doesnt triggered. i googled it everywhere but couldnt solve the problem.

I tried to use `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating` but still i am facing this problem.

Here is my code:

```
public void setRecurringAlarmsForPeriod(Integer sh, Integer sm, Integer    eh, Integer em, Integer interval)
{

    this.interval = interval;
    startHour = sh;
    startMinute = sm;
    endHour = eh;
    endMinute = em;
    reminderCount = 0;
    Integer currentStartHour = startHour;
    Integer currentStartMinute = startMinute;

    while (currentStartHour < endHour || (currentStartHour.equals(endHour) && currentStartMinute <= endMinute))
    {
        setRecurringAlarm(currentStartHour, currentStartMinute, reminderCount);
        reminderCount++;

        currentStartMinute += interval;
        if (currentStartMinute >= 60)
        {
            currentStartMinute -= 60;
            currentStartHour++;
        }
    }


    savePersistent();
}
```

in the below code i am creating the alarm by alarmmanager for some periods in a day

```
private void setRecurringAlarm(Integer hour, Integer minute, Integer index)
{


    Calendar notificationTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    notificationTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    notificationTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    notificationTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    notificationTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.activity.getApplicationContext(), WaterReminderReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.activity.getApplicationContext(), index, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if (alarmManager != null)
    {
        try {

            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "exceptipon   :" , e.toString());
        }

        Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "Alarm Set For", hour + " " + minute);
        Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "Alarm Date", notificationTime.getTime().toString());

    }
    else
    {
        Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "ALARMS", "WAS NULL");
    }




}
```

Comment: I think its about the "PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT". i changed it to "0" and gonna try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed this code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.activity.getApplicationContext(), index, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

to this then it worked.

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.activity.getApplicationContext(), index, intent, 0);
```